# How to configure texlive in Xenial

Tags: 16.04, latex

I used to use `texconfig` to configure texlive on my previous Ubuntu installations. 
I just installed Xenial and texlive and I tried to configure texlive as usual but, to my surprise, there is no texconfig any longer anywhere.
How am I supposed to configure texlive now? Or is it a bug in texlive distribution?

Comment: This problem has been solved in TeX section: cfr: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306867/add-babel-to-plain-tex-texlive-ubuntu-16-04